# Restricted mean survival time per patient

Tags: r, survival, censoring

Apologies for the basic question (I have a clinical training background therefore am not so experienced on the stats front).

Is it possible to calculate the restricted mean survival time for each individual patient? And is this what the 'pseudomean' function from R package 'pseudo' is doing (using pv apporach)? I have only encountered the use of RMST in group comparisons, and I think the inclusion of the word 'mean' meant that I had only thought of it in the context of groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although an individual patient in a simple survival model might only have a single event time, it's possible to estimate the restricted mean survival of a *cohort of patients* having the same covariate values as an individual patient. For example, with the R `survfit.coxph()` function and a Cox model, for each `newdata` you provide you get a survival curve "representative of a cohort whose covariates correspond to the values in `newdata`" (quoting from the manual page). Restricted mean survival can then be calculated from that survival curve.

That's not what's going on with the [`pseudo` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=pseudo), however. That package provides tools for another way to deal with censored event times, a way that allows a standard type of regression to be used.

Pseudo-observations are nicely explained in [this document](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X1001000308)*. A pseudo-observation of a patient's restricted mean survival is effectively the difference in restricted mean survival between a data set including and excluding that patient. Pseudo-observations are available for all patients whether their event times are censored or not, and they can be used as outcome variables in a regression fit by a [generalized estimating equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_estimating_equation). That, for example, could allow you to evaluate the associations of covariate values with restricted mean survival.

---

*Stata Journal (2010) 10, Number 3, pp. 408–422

Comment: Thanks so much. That's a great help and has cleared my understanding up. Using pseudo-observations to fit a GEE is exactly what I was hoping was possible (my data does not not satisfy the PH assumption).